# Unable to get Nvidia GT720 work fine beside hybrid Intel graphic - laptop with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, cuda, blender

My 1st post on AskUbuntu!

I have an ASUS X75V laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.
The graphic equipement is hybrid : an Intel graphic card (default card, recognized by Ubuntu) and a Nvidia GeForce GT720M, not natively recognized by Ubuntu, and that I am struggling to get working fine, especially for use as GPU (via CUDA) on Blender.
I managed to install the Nvidia driver nvidia-340 which gives me access to the Nvidia X Server Settings from the Unity launcher.
BUT, since I installed the Nvidia card and use it instead of the Intel one, my graphic performance, anywhere and anytime is slow and has lots of screen refresh issues. Also, I just bought an additional monitor (HDMI) which when connected to the laptop makes all the computer respond slowly, especially graphically.
Also, in Blender, after many tries of installing CUDA, Bumblebee and Prime, I haven't managed to have GPU/CUDA available and working on Blender, even though the Nvidia is installed. My Blender is 2.72.

So, it looks like my Nvidia driver, even though installed, is messing somewhere, unable to work with its actual power, and for now, delivering even lower performance than the Intel hybrid graphic card.

Here is the choice I've got in the Additional Drivers panel :

- NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331-updates (proprietary)
- NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331 (libre)
- XX.org - new display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (libre)
- NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.65 from nvidia-340 (libre) (THE ONE I USE NOW)

Have I made the right choice ? Should the list include another version which would work better ?

I've tried several re-install of the nvidia drivers, which several times led to a big crash at the boot of Ubuntu, crashed in the Xorg, or something around that :P... which has cost me a lot of time, so, not wishing to make more mess, I come here to find solid help ! I have a computer friend who helped me recover my boot, but who didn't find where the deep issue is.
Thanks a lot if you can help to locate what's wrong and if it can be fixed ! :)

Comment: I successfully got things working in 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/952426/severe-under-performance-of-cuda-vs-windows-make-intel-primary-gpu/953051#953051

Answer (score 0):

Pease read till the end before you get upset! ;-)

1. Disable hybrid mode in the BIOS, boot only with NVidia and get your GPU working in a stable way.
   Head to [the xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to accomplish this.
   Use your computer like that for at least a day until it is stable
2. Now boot in Intel mode, use it for a day as well and see whether you have any issues there (never heard of any, but Murphy etc.
3. Now head to the [Bumblebee PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/ubuntu/stable), and get their software installed.
4. Boot again in Hybrid mode.

### Done!

Comment: Thank you Fabby for this method ! I'm going to try it, and will let your know how it goes.

Comment: Argh, nowhere in the BIOS appears something about hybrid graphics. I looked everywhere, I saw nothing concerning the graphic cards...
Do you know any alternative to this first step ?

Comment: Look for a BIOS upgrade.  If that doesn't work, go ahead, **but** it could be you end up in a text terminal and you'll have to type everything using the keyboard, no mouse, no pretty windows,  just you and a terminal!  And as you're too low on reputation, I can't even take you into a chat room, so I would definitely try upgrading the BIOS first.

Comment: OK, thank you again, I see what I can do about it. Cheers !

Comment: @Ludo38: as you're a reputation 1 user: to don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: @Ludo38: Aparently it worked for someone else, as I just got an upvote!  **;-)**